# Automatic backspace

Tags: keyboard

I am using Gnome 3.36.8 on Ubuntu 20.0.3. All of a sudden (since yesterday) a few spooky things have started happening to my laptop. The airplane mode gets switched on and the keyboard acts weird i.e. the backspace starts acting on its own if I leave the keyboard untouched for 2 to 3 minutes. The delete key is also not working.

I am keeping this message short because the backspace might start eating back all the words again.

Comment: Try a different keyboard, and see if the problems go away.

Comment: It does sound very much like a hardware issue I’m afraid.

Comment: Just enter the "BIOS" setup and go to a field that you can enter text freely. See if this happens there too. If so, you will need to replace your keyboard.